# Does the region surrounding a bar magnet have a greater abundance of virtual photons, or more energetic virtual photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, virtual-particles

Does the region surrounding a bar magnet have a greater abundance of virtual photons, or more energetic (but the same number) virtual photons when compared to a region further away from the bar magnet?